# Job with Kubernetes Pod Operator fail while running with kubernetes Executor

Tags: kubernetes, airflow-scheduler, kubernetes-pod, airflow

I am currently using kubernetes executor with Airflow and all the operators in airflow are working correctly but All the dags scheduled in airflow containing kubernetes pod operator are failing.No logs are being displayed on airflow UI. I can only find Following error logs on the scheduler pod.

```
[2019-11-26 13:32:44,874] {kubernetes_executor.py:362} INFO - Event: kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9 had an event of type MODIFIED
[2019-11-26 13:32:44,881] {kubernetes_executor.py:398} INFO - Event: kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9 Failed
[2019-11-26 13:32:44,907] {kubernetes_executor.py:362} INFO - Event: kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9 had an event of type DELETED
[2019-11-26 13:32:44,915] {kubernetes_executor.py:398} INFO - Event: kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9 Failed
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,850] {kubernetes_executor.py:506} INFO - Attempting to finish pod; pod_id: kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9; stat
e: failed; labels: {u'try_number': '1', u'execution_date': '2019-11-26T13_32_35.285788_plus_00_00', u'airflow-worker': '45390e71-9831-4ea4-9077-a2753eff16ae', u'tas
k_id': 'passing-task', u'dag_id': 'kubernetes-operator'}
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,854] {kubernetes_executor.py:625} INFO - Checking 1 task instances.
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,855] {kubernetes_executor.py:635} INFO - Found matching task kubernetes-operator-passing-task (2019-11-26 13:32:35.285788+00:00) with current s
tate of queued
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,858] {kubernetes_executor.py:506} INFO - Attempting to finish pod; pod_id: kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9; stat
e: failed; labels: {u'try_number': '1', u'execution_date': '2019-11-26T13_32_35.285788_plus_00_00', u'airflow-worker': '45390e71-9831-4ea4-9077-a2753eff16ae', u'tas
k_id': 'passing-task', u'dag_id': 'kubernetes-operator'}
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,862] {kubernetes_executor.py:625} INFO - Checking 1 task instances.
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,863] {kubernetes_executor.py:635} INFO - Found matching task kubernetes-operator-passing-task (2019-11-26 13:32:35.285788+00:00) with current s
tate of queued
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,866] {kubernetes_executor.py:819} INFO - Changing state of ((u'kubernetes-operator', u'passing-task', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 26, 13, 32, 3
5, 285788, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 1), u'failed', 'kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9', '688810') to failed
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,871] {kubernetes_executor.py:855} INFO - Deleted pod: (u'kubernetes-operator', u'passing-task', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 26, 13, 32, 35, 285
788, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 1)
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,872] {kubernetes_executor.py:819} INFO - Changing state of ((u'kubernetes-operator', u'passing-task', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 26, 13, 32, 3
5, 285788, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 1), u'failed', 'kubernetesoperatorpassingtask-94a53570a63440e9ac11206e5a5e5da9', '688811') to failed
[2019-11-26 13:32:46,876] {kubernetes_executor.py:855} INFO - Deleted pod: (u'kubernetes-operator', u'passing-task', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 26, 13, 32, 35, 285
788, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 1)
[2019-11-26 13:32:50,854] {scheduler_job.py:1288} INFO - Executor reports execution of kubernetes-operator.passing-task execution_date=2019-11-26 13:32:35.285788+00
:00 exited with status failed for try_number 1
[2019-11-26 13:32:50,859] {scheduler_job.py:1304} ERROR - Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance: kubernetes-operator.passing-task 2019-11-26 13:32:35.285788+
00:00 [queued]> finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?
[2019-11-26 13:32:50,860] {dagbag.py:92} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags/kubernetes_pod_operator_test.py
[2019-11-26 13:32:50,866] {taskinstance.py:1058} ERROR - Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance: kubernetes-operator.passing-task 2019-11-26 13:32:35.285788+0
0:00 [queued]> finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?
None
[2019-11-26 13:32:50,868] {taskinstance.py:1089} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
```

The code of my Dag is:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
default_args = {
   'owner': 'airflow',
   'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
}
dag = DAG(
   dag_id='kubernetes-operator',
   default_args=default_args,
   schedule_interval=None,
)
task1 = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                          image="Python:3.6",
                          cmds=["Python","-c"],
                          arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="passing-test",
                          task_id="passing-task",
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag
)
```

Comment: do you tried to check why the pod is going in the failed state?

Comment: As @c4f4t0r requested, please update your question with more details as Pod Logs and describe outputs. First thing is to understand why it's failing, so we can know if the problem is on k8s or Airflow side.

Comment: The issue is resolved,it was because of conflict between two projects on the cluster.

Comment: @AnmolKalra can you explain more what the issue was.. I am seeing the same issue.